swig minimal pointers example
I have a cpp file called "pointers.cpp":
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pointers.h"

void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res){
  *res = (char *)malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);
  strcpy(*res,str1);
  strcat(*res,str2);
}

with an associated header file "pointers.h":
void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res);

I am building a python extension module using SWIG with the help of the following interface file "pointers.i":
%module pointers

%{
#include "pointers.h"
%}

// This input typemap declares that char** requires no input parameter.
// Instead, the address of a local char* is used to call the function.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) char** (char* tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// After the function is called, the char** parameter contains a malloc'ed char* pointer.
// Construct a Python Unicode object (I'm using Python 3) and append it to
// any existing return value for the wrapper.
%typemap(argout) char** (PyObject* obj) %{
    obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,obj);
%}

// The malloc'ed pointer is no longer needed, so make sure it is freed.
%typemap(freearg) char** %{
    free(*$1);
%}

// Now that the typemap exists, let swig wrap the header.
%include "pointers.h"

I build the extension module with the commands
swig -v -c++ -python example.i
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

and try it in python as:
import pointers
result = pointers.conc('Hello ','World!');
print(result)

I found this example here: swig char ** as a pointer to a char *
Now, I would like to use char** as input to be able to do something like
import pointers

strings = ["Hello ", "World", "!"]
result = pointers.concat_all(strings, len(strings))
print(result)  # Output: Hello World!

How should I modify the interface file? Thanks!

You will need to define in and freearg typemaps. The in typemap should iterate over $input which will be a PyList. Allocate $1 to be a char** of the given length, then convert all the strings one by one. Finally, in the freearg typemap, free $1.
